# Highcharts : yAxis, values rounded to a maximum of two decimal places

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The code of my graph is this (take data from a php page and then adds some series):

```
$('#grafico_1').highcharts({

chart: {
    type: 'line',
    zoomType: 'xy',
    animation : false,
    events: {
    selection: function(event) {

        if(event.resetSelection){

            setTimeout(function(e){

                var chart = $('#grafico_1').highcharts();
                var extreme = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();

                var mio_min = parseFloat(proprieta_temperatura_aperto[34]);
                var mio_max = parseFloat(proprieta_temperatura_aperto[35]);

                if(extreme.dataMin < mio_min){
                    mio_min = extreme.dataMin;
                }
                if(extreme.dataMax > mio_max){
                    mio_max = extreme.dataMax;
                }

                chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(mio_min,mio_max);

                $("#temperatura_min_max_rilevato").html("Min "+extreme.dataMin+"°C - Max "+extreme.dataMax+"°C");
                //console.log("zoom - ");

            }, 10);
        }else{

            setTimeout(function(e){
                var chart = $('#grafico_1').highcharts();
                var extreme = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
                $("#temperatura_min_max_rilevato").html("Min "+extreme.dataMin+"°C - Max "+extreme.dataMax+"°C");
                //console.log("zoom + "+JSON.stringify(extreme));
            }, 50);

        }

    }
},
},

credits : {
   enabled : false
},

title: {
    text: 'Grafico di Oggi'
},

xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    title: {
        text: false
    }
},

yAxis: [
   {
        title: {
            text: false
        },
        labels: {
        format: '{value}°C',
    },
        //ceiling : parseFloat(proprieta_temperatura_aperto[35]),
        //floor: parseFloat(proprieta_temperatura_aperto[34]),
        max : parseFloat(proprieta_temperatura_aperto[35]),
        min: parseFloat(proprieta_temperatura_aperto[34]),


    },
    {
        title: {
            text: false
        },
        min: 0,
        max : 1,
        ceiling:1,
        floor : 0,
        //tickLength : 1,
        opposite: true,
        tickInterval: 1,
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                if (this.value == 0 || this.value == 1){
                    return this.value;
                }else{
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
],


tooltip: {

    formatter: function() {

        var s = '<b>Data</b> '+Highcharts.dateFormat('%H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br><b>Temperatura</b> ' + this.y + '°C<br/>';

        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {

            if(point.series.name != "Temperatura"){
                s += '<b>' + point.series.name +'</b> : '+ point.y + '<br>';
            }

        });

        return s;
    },
    shared: true,
    backgroundColor: '#FCFFC5'
},

plotOptions: {
   line : {
       turboThreshold: 0,
    },
    series: {
        animation: false,
        marker: {
           enabled: false
        }
    }
},

series: []

});
```

the problem occurs when run one (or more) zoom on the graphs , and on the y-axis the values ​​are listed with more than two decimal places. I would like to limit to two the maximum number of decimal places.

[image]

I think i have to change this field ([format](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.format))

```
yAxis: [
    {
    labels: {
       format: '{value}°C',
         },
```

but I do not know how.

Comment: Does this [link](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting) maybe help? So it might just be `{value:.2f}`?

Answer (score 3):

Try to write the value as `{value:.2f}`, as proposed here: [link](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting)